# Modsecurity : Creating a new Request Header from SecRule

Tags: mod-security

Consider the following redirect SecRule which is activated from a Lua script

```
SecRule &TX:SQLI "@eq 1" "id:'129793',phase:2,t:none,redirect:http://www.example.com/failed.html,msg:'SQLi Injection Payload Found',setvar:REQUEST_HEADERS:Blocked"
```

When the variable `tx.sqli` is given a value the rule is activated. The redirection is successful, but the rule attempts to create a new "Blocked" request header. However, the creation is unsuccessful.

The log in the debugger outputs the following:

```
Could not set variable "REQUEST_HEADERS.Blocked" as the collection does not exist.
```

This is obviously incorrect. How does Modsecurity create new request header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ModSecurity most of the standard collections (including REQUEST_HEADERS) are read only. You would therefore set a variable not a REQUEST_HEADER.

It doesn't usually make sense to set a REQUEST_HEADER. A RESPONSE_HEADER I can see more use for but its similarly read-only and to alter that you need to use the standard mod_headers module:

```
#Use ModSecurity to set an env variable
SecRule &TX:SQLI "@eq 1" "id:'129793',phase:2,set-env:BLOCK_RESPONSE"

#Use mod_header to set Header based on that env variable
Header set Blocked "True" env=BLOCK_RESPONSE
```

Though honestly not sure how or if that would work with a redirect as a ModSecurity action or whether that happens immediately.

Comment: What you're saying makes a lot of sense, thank you. I store the details of the log file, including the request headers. I just wanted to store the fact that something had been blocked; hence creating the additional request header.

I will use this `mod_header` function; I saw it referenced elsewhere. I guess that this is not inserted into the ModSecurity config file, but somewhere in Apache.

Comment: You could try the same thing I gave but instead of "Header set" use "RequestHeader set"

Comment: Sure thing, will give it a go and get back to you. I just need to first figure out where to put this mod_header line first.

Comment: Your answer was correct in all senses. First, the code that you provided above was correct. Second, you were also correct in your ascertain that a `deny` or a `redirect` action is executed before the write to a Response Header. Perhaps there is another way of communicating down the chain that some traffic was denied or redirected.