# ModSecurity and custom headers

Tags: apache-2.4, varnish, http-headers, mod-security

How can we add a custom header using the 'msg' value from a ModSecurity rule, for all rules triggered? I'm basically trying to track the ModSec block reason at an edge point (Varnish) based on Apache's response.

For example, I would like:

`SecRule REQUEST_URI "/modsectest" "log,deny,status:406,phase:1,t:none,id:9084310,msg:'ModSec Log Test'"`

To add a `'X-ModSec-Block'` response header with the value `'ModSec Log Test'` in this case. I understand this might be better suited with setenv + mod_headers due to blocks being done at different phases, and found [Modsecurity : Creating a new Request Header from SecRule](https://serverfault.com/questions/796088/modsecurity-creating-a-new-request-header-from-secrule) which seems similar to this scenario, just that it's not quite working out for me. Any help is greatly appreciated!